# Passing querystring variables between fancybox

Tags: javascript, fancybox, query-string

Im wanting to pass some URL querystring variables between fancyboxes.

I have one fancybox open with an overview - then in that overview, I want to link to a youtube video in a new fancybox (replacing the first) passing some variables to the new window for titles etc.

Any advice?

Thanks! :)